# set of integers as input to print sum of their cubes

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this question. I tried many different ways, I get the correct output but the testcases are not passed(I dont know what are those testcases). I cant figure what is wrong.

**Question:**

Given a set of integers (separated by space), write a program to print the sum of their cubes.

Sample Input:

1 2 3 4 5

Sample Output:

225

Sample Input:

1 2

Sample Output:

9

**Solution 2:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Test{

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        int num,sum=0;

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String data=sc.nextLine();

        Scanner sc2=new Scanner(data);
        while(sc2.hasNextInt())
        {
            num=sc2.nextInt();
            sum=sum+num*num*num;
        }

        System.out.print(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't have the testcase input and output and an indication of what is incorrect about your output we really can't help.  This is like an auto mechanic being asked to diagnose a problem without being allowed to touch or attempt to start the vehicle.

Comment: @Ash: can you confirm testing code for the above testcases runs correctly?

Comment: @Artur: I didn't get you

Comment: Is this a hackerrank challenge? If so give link. Does challenge specify limit on input, i.e. how big can numbers be? Also, learn to indent your code for human readability. Remember, cube can be a very large number, so I think [answer by SlowAndSteady](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37452675/5221149) is the answer.

Comment: No it is not hackerrang. This is an online test for students

Comment: @Ash Show us the link to your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Used long instead of int. Thanks to Andreas and Matsev for the `BigInteger` idea.

```
import java.util.*;
class Test{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        long num,sum=0;

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String data=sc.nextLine(); 
        Scanner sc2=new Scanner(data);
        while(sc2.hasNextInt())
        {
            num=sc2.nextInt();
            sum=sum+num*num*num;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should fix the indentations of this answer, then accept it as a self-answer, so others can easily see what the solution was.

Answer (score 2):

Your test cases most likely contain large integers as input. Use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to hold their cubes.

Comment: I believe this is the right answer. Cube will overflow `int` for `input >= 1291` and will overflow `long` for `input >= 2097152`. `BigInteger` won't overflow *(unless you run out of memory)*.

Answer (score 1):

*Update (by Andreas): Added boilerplate imports since [@Ash seems unable to figure that out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452591/37453268?noredirect=1#comment62408975_37453268).*

If you would like an implementation in more functional style (using Java 8+ streams), here is another suggestion:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = line.split("\\s+");

        BigInteger sum = Arrays.asList(numbers)
                .stream()
                .map(BigInteger::new)
                .map(bigInteger -> bigInteger.pow(3))
                .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

---

Update: After @Andreas comments, the implementation can be even shorter:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = scan.nextLine();

        BigInteger sum = Pattern.compile("\\s+")
                .splitAsStream(line)
                .map(s -> new BigInteger(s).pow(3))
                .reduce(BigInteger::add)
                .orElse(BigInteger.ZERO);

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Better way would be `Pattern.compile("\\s+").splitAsStream(line).map(s -> new BigInteger(s).pow(3))...`. Eliminates the intermediate array, and since you're doing a lambda expression anyway, might as well do the `new BigInteger(s)` in it, instead of chaining two `map()` operations. May also do `...reduce(BigInteger::add).orElse(BigInteger.ZERO)` to eliminate one `add()` operation, though the performance improvement of that would be negligible, but allow the alternate `...reduce(BigInteger::add).get()` so an exception is thrown when no numbers are given.

Comment: Actually `orElse(BigInteger.ZERO)` can't fire, since `splitAsStream()` will always send at least one value down the stream, so `get()` is safe to use and won't cause exception. Blank input would cause exception upstream when `new BigInteger()` is called on empty string. That's true for both `line.split` and `splitAsStream` versions.

Comment: @matsev: I tried ur code but there are many errors like illegal start of expression bracket, semicolons expected

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the comment. I was not aware of the `splitAsStream()` method, nice to know if you are dealing with large data volumes. I thought about just using just one map operation, but decided that having two map operations makes the easier to read. Nevertheless, I have updated the post based on your suggestion. Btw, you need the `getOrElse()` constructs is needed to handle empty strings (`new BigInteger()` will not be called if there is no value).

Comment: @matsev `"".split("\\s+")` will return an array of one element with a empty string, i.e. `new String[] { "" }`. `Arrays.asList(numbers)` is then a list of one empty string, and `stream()` will send an empty string down the pipeline, causing `new BigInteger("")` to be called. Same when using `splitAsStream`. So, empty input means `NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger`.

Comment: @Ash There are no errors in either version of the displayed code. If you have errors, then you are likely missing some imports, e.g. `import java.math.*; import java.util.*; import java.util.regex.*;`. Any good IDE would help you figure out the required imports. This is similar to the [comment I gave you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452591/set-of-integers-as-input-to-print-sum-of-their-cubes/37453268?noredirect=1#comment62407005_37452940) in the other answer.

Comment: @matsev `orElseGet(() -> BigInteger.ZERO)` should be `orElse(BigInteger.ZERO)`. No need for delayed execution through the use of a lambda expression when it's a constant. But as explained earlier, the *stream* cannot be empty, so a simple `get()` will suffice.

Comment: @Ash Try to actually copy/paste the code we *give* to you. 1) `import java.lang.Math.*` should be `import java.math.*`. 2) `orElse` should be `orElseGet`. 3) `(() -> (BigInteger.ZERO)` should be `(() -> BigInteger.ZERO)`. 4) `import java.io.*` is not used and can be removed.

Comment: @Matsev: Andreas Your code does not work in the compiler I am working. It works in another.

Comment: @Ash Please check your IDE / compiler configuration and use the imports as added by Andreas

Comment: @Ash Streams were added in Java 8, so it won't work with an older compiler.

Comment: I used long instead of int. The test cases passed. Thanks a lot @Andreas and matsev

Answer (score 1):

I modified my answer according to your needs. Now it gives sum of cubes of numbers in given input which are separated by spaces. Check this :-

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.util.Collections.list;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfCubes {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    String integers="";
    Integer num=0;
    BigInteger cube;
    BigInteger sum=new BigInteger("0");

    System.out.println("Enter Integers seperated by space");
    integers=in.nextLine();

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String s : integers.split("\\s")) {  
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));  
    }
    list.toArray();

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        num=list.get(i);
        cube=BigInteger.valueOf(num*num*num);
        sum=sum.add(cube);
    }

    System.out.println("Sum of Cubes of numbers in given input = "+sum);
}
```

}

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this code in another compiler. The output it gives is incorrect. For eg., for 1 2 it gives 27 which should be 9

Comment: @Ash: You asked for cube of sum of input digits. What else you want. 1+2=3. and 3*3*3=27.

Comment: @Ash: I got it correct now. You need sum of cubes of numbers separated by spaces. I modified my solution. It is perfect now. Check it.

Comment: Thanks.. But this code also does not pass the test cases.

Comment: What are your test cases ? If I don't know them how can I help ?

Comment: I also don't know the test cases. It only shows 0 of 4 test cases passed

Comment: So sad. Anyway, I wish you Best of Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your Solution 2 a little bit. Could you please confirm whether this passes the test or not.

```
 import java.math.BigInteger;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Test{

 public static void main(String []args)
    {

        BigInteger sum=new BigInteger.ZERO;

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String data=sc.nextLine();

        Scanner sc2=new Scanner(data);

        while(sc2.hasNextInt())
        {
            BigInteger num=new BigInteger(String.valueOf(sc2.nextInt()));
            sum= sum.add(num.multiply(num).multiply(num));
        }

        System.out.print(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent code for human readability. `new BigInteger("0")` should be `BigInteger.ZERO`. You assume inputs will fit in an `int`, so replace with `new BigInteger(sc2.next())`, allowing unlimited numeric values.

Comment: @Ash You need `import java.math.BigInteger` and `import java.util.Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;

class csum

{

public static void main(String args[])

{

```
 Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

long csum=0;

 while(in.hasNextInt())

{

  csum=csum+(long)Math.pow(in.nextInt(),3);

}  

System.out.println(csum);
```

}

}

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         long num,count=0;
         Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
         while(in.hasNextInt())
         {
             num=in.nextInt();
             count+=Math.pow(num,3);
         }
         System.out.println(count);
    }
```

or

```
    public Static vid main(String args[])
    {
         long count;
         Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
         String s=in.nextLine();
         String[] t=s.split(" ");
         for(i=0;i<t.length;i++)
         {
             count+=Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(t[i]),3);
         }
         System.out.println(count);
    }
```